# 'Error: getaddrinfo' after trying to run 'truffle unbox react'

Tags: solidity, truffle, react

After installing truffle globally `npm install -g truffle`, I'll make an empty folder and try to run `truffle unbox react` but I end up getting an error message show below:

[image]

I have the current versions of:

```
Truffle v5.5.10 (core: 5.5.10)

Ganache v^7.0.3

Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)

Node v12.18.3

Web3.js v1.5.3

npm 6.14.6
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What OS are you running this in? Seems to be more related to your system being able to resolve domains. I've run on a mac and your commands work fine.

Comment: I'm on a Windows 10

Comment: Seems like you can't connect to github. Are you sure nothing is blocking the connection to github networking wise?

Comment: Yea I assume there isn't any blocked connection. I mean I could access github.com through the browser...

Answer (score 0):

According to their github page (https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/2995#issue-604582346) It seems like other people have come across this issue.

Basically I just added the following line in the `/etc/hosts` file:

```
151.101.56.133 raw.githubusercontent.com
```